# Move existing articles to another group in Gnus

Tags: email, emacs, mailing-lists, gnus

I set up [`nnmail-split-methods`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Splitting-Mail.html) to separate mail coming from my mailing list from anything else:

```
(setq nnmail-split-methods '(("vladimir.lenin" "From:.*vladimir\.lenin")
                             ("mail.misc" "")))
```

New mail will now appear in `vladimir.lenin` group, but the already existing ones will still remain at `mail.misc`. How do i quickly move all articles matching the regex from one group to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my probably excess and sub-optimal solution, as i couldn't find the idiomatic way. Default keybindings for every command are given in parentheses.

First of all, set the variable [`gnus-move-split-methods`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Mail-Group-Commands.html#index-gnus_002dmove_002dsplit_002dmethods-1620) similar to your [`nnmail-split-methods`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Splitting-Mail.html) variable. Notice that the syntax in the 1<sup>st</sup> variable is `("^From:.*eliezer" "mail.hpmor")`, while in the 2<sup>nd</sup> variable is `("mail.hpmor" "^From:.*eliezer")`. For example, my `gnus-move-split-methods` is:

```
(setq gnus-move-split-methods
      '(("^Sender:.*abbie.*" "mail.abbie")
        ("" "mail.misc")))
```

Open the group and make it show all articles. Call [`gnus-summary-limit-to-headers`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Limiting.html#index-g_t_002f-h-_0028Summary_0029-932) (<kbd>/ h</kbd>) and specify regex (in my example `"Sender:.*abbie"`) to show only articles you want to move.

Use [keyboard macros](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros) to facilitate moving, start macro by [`kmacro-start-macro`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Keyboard-Macro.html) (<kbd>C-x (</kbd>), then move your first article with [`gnus-summary-move-article`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Mail-Group-Commands.html#index-gnus_002dsummary_002dmove_002darticle-1591) <kbd>B m</kbd>, then repeat the macro by `kmacro-end-and-call-macro` (<kbd>C-x e</kbd>) and specify the number of repetitions with a universal argument (<kbd>C-u</kbd>).

If you don't know how many times you should repeat the macro, you can count the number of articles left by selecting all ([`mark-whole-buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Marking-Objects.html)) and counting with [`count-words-region`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Position-Info.html). Don't use 0 as a universal article, as for some reason it won't finish. Remember, as mails are moved physically from one folder to another, the whole operation might take time depending on how many mail you have.

If you use `nnml` as a mail backend, run [`gnus-group-compact-group`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Misc-Group-Stuff.html) (<kbd>G z</kbd>) on your group, so that Gnus gives you the correct article count. This also may take time depending on the amount of mail.

Notes:

- As you see, because you set `gnus-move-split-methods`, when you move the article, the default group proposed in the prompt is correct.
- [`gnus-summary-toggle-header`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Article-Washing.html) (<kbd>t</kbd>) is helpful to find which header you need to filter with.
- Sometimes there is no `Sender:` header, so I use `Cc:.*abbie` regexp too. You might see that headers are frequently inconsistent, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

From the summary buffer of the `mail.misc group`, limit the view to the articles whose author is "vladimir.lenin" (`gnus-summary-limit-to-author`), then mark them all for processing (`gnus-uu-mark-all`), and then move all the marked articles to the `vladimir.lenin` group (`gnus-summary-move-article`). The complete key sequence is as follows:

```
/ a vladimir\.lenin RET M P a B m vladimir.lenin RET / w
```